# Generate csv from excel file with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I've been trying to generate a csv file from an excel that has this format

```
ConceptId   |   31   |   32   |   33   |   34   |   35   |   36   |
EmployeeId  |        |        |        |        |        |        |
    1       |        |  44.00 |  56.00 |        |        |        |
    2       |        |        |        |        |        |        |
    3       |        |        |  44.00 |  5.00  |  5.00  |        |
    4       | 445.00 |  5.00  |        |        |        |        |
    5       |        |        |  65.00 |  56.00 |  65.00 |        |
```

So I want a csv to look like this

```
EmployeeId  |   ConceptId   |  Amount   |  
    1       |       32      |  44.00    |
    1       |       33      |  56.00    |
    3       |       33      |  44.00    |
    3       |       34      |   5.00    |
    4       |       31      | 445.00    |
    4       |       32      |   5,00    |
    5       |       33      |  65.00    |
    5       |       34      |  56,00    |
    5       |       35      |  65,00    |
```

I'm using pandas in python but I have junior-level coding skills so it's been hard to me to iterate over rows to generate the csv that excludes the empty cells

This is the code I have so far that convert my excel file to a csv file exactly as it is

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('excelfile.XLSX', index_col=0, header=None)

df.to_csv('csvfile.csv')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to `stack` the dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel('excelfile.XLSX', index_col=0, header=None)
df = df.stack().rename('Amount').reset_index()
df.to_csv('csvfile.csv', index=False)
```

The resulting csv file will be:

```
EmployeeId,ConceptId,Amount
1,32,44.0
1,33,56.0
3,33,44.0
3,34,5.0
3,35,5.0
4,31,445.0
4,32,5.0
5,33,65.0
5,34,56.0
5,35,65.0
```

Comment: Thanks, Serge! That helps me a lot